# What is the Maximum data which sqlite database(local database) can handle in windows phone app / windows 8 metro app?

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-phone-8

i am using a sqlite as a local database in my windows phone app and windows 8 metro app , i want to know

1)What is the maximum size limitation sqlite database in windows phone app / windows 8 metro app ????

2)How much data can sqlite can handle in windows phone app / windows 8 metro app ??

Please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're talking about working memory instead of storage (of which SQLite can easily handle several gigabytes). SQLite itself doesn't use much memory by default. It will depend very much on how your application uses it.

So if you have long transactions, that may cause larger memory consumption as does having a lot of simultaneous prepared statements. Also, if you want to tune memory consumption, there are a number of configuration options, some of them compile-time, which you can use to have it behave even more conservative: http://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html

Generally speaking, a Windows 8 app probably won't need such optimization, though, which should only be required for much smaller integrated systems. If it runs Windows 8, running SQLite is the smallest of concerns ^^